# How does Fire Shield interact with Net (and other flammable stuffs strike it)?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

Assuming that net is flammable (since the description never says so). When a net hit a character protected by *Fire Shield*, would the net be ignited? Or would the net be safe simply because it is not a creature? (Fire Shield only says it would cause damage to "creature".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *Fire shield* doesn't affect the net, it damages the attacker

[Fire Shield](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fireShield.htm) says:

> This spell wreathes you in flame and causes damage **to each creature that attacks you** in melee. (...) Any creature striking you with its body or a handheld weapon deals normal damage, but at the same time **the attacker** takes 1d6 points of damage +1 point per caster level

It does not cause damage to the weapon that attacks you.

Comment: I guess so. Just want to make sure.